# SQL selection query linked to two controls with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am getting a syntax error with the below SQL select query.  Using the first where clause there is no issue. As soon as I add the second, I get a syntax error message.

```
sql_get = "SELECT tblContacts.ID AS IDResource
                  , tblImmages.Immage
                  , tblContacts.Foto
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.CurrentLevel
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.GeneralNotesSymbol
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.ID
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.Status
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.SkillLevelPie
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.SubProcessID
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.Contact
                  , tblTeams.Team
                  , tblValueChain01.MacroProcess
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelOneStatus
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.AsOfDateL1
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelTwoStatus
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.AsOfDateL2
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelThreeStatus
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.AsOfDateL3
                  , " & _
                  "tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelFourStatus 
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.AsOfDateL4
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.GeneralNotes
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelOneNotes
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelTwoNotes
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelThreeNotes
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelFourNotes
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelOneNotesSymbol
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelTwoNotesSymbol
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelThreeNotesSymbol
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelFourNotesSymbol
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.ExpectedCmplDateL1
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.ExpectedCmplDateL2
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.ExpectedCmplDateL3 
                  , tblSkillsMatrix01.ExpectedCmplDateL4 
             FROM (tblTeams 
                  INNER JOIN (tblContacts 
                             INNER JOIN (tblSkillsMatrix01 
                                        INNER JOIN tblImmages ON tblSkillsMatrix01.SkillLevelPie = tblImmages.ID) 
                             ON tblContacts.ID = tblSkillsMatrix01.Contact) 
                  ON tblTeams.ID = tblContacts.Team) 
                  INNER JOIN tblValueChain01 ON tblContacts.Group = tblValueChain01.IDMacroProcesso 
            WHERE [tblValueChain01].[MacroProcess]= '" & Me.MacroProcess & "'" 
               and WHERE [tblSkillsMatrix01].[SubProcessID]= '" & Form_frmValueChain07e.ID & "'"

Me.frmValueChain14.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```

Comment: You might start by formatting the query in the query so others can read it.

Comment: Marchese II Chihuahua @ could you write your whole query at once?

Comment: I reformatted it.  is it better?

Comment: (tblTeams INNER JOIN 
 (tblContacts INNER JOIN 
  (tblSkillsMatrix01 INNER JOIN tblImmages ON tblSkillsMatrix01.SkillLevelPie = tblImmages.ID) 
 ON tblContacts.ID = tblSkillsMatrix01.Contact) 
ON tblTeams.ID = tblContacts.Team) 

INNER JOIN tblValueChain01 
ON tblContacts.Group = tblValueChain01.IDMacroProcesso 
WHERE [tblValueChain01].[MacroProcess]= '" & Me.MacroProcess & "' 
and [tblSkillsMatrix01].[SubProcessID]= '" & Form_frmValueChain07e.ID & "'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `WHERE` clauses in single `SELECT` statement. You don't need two `WHERE` clauses.

Replace this

```
WHERE [tblValueChain01].[MacroProcess]= '" & Me.MacroProcess & "'" 
and WHERE [tblSkillsMatrix01].[SubProcessID]= '" & Form_frmValueChain07e.ID & "'"
```

with this [if the `SubProcessID` **IS NOT** a number]

```
WHERE [tblValueChain01].[MacroProcess]= '" & Me.MacroProcess & "' and [tblSkillsMatrix01].[SubProcessID]= '" & Form_frmValueChain07e.ID & "'"
```

or with this [if the `SubProcessID` **IS** a number]

```
WHERE [tblValueChain01].[MacroProcess]= '" & Me.MacroProcess & "' and [tblSkillsMatrix01].[SubProcessID]= " & Form_frmValueChain07e.ID & ""
```

and try..

Comment: I am getting a compilation error highlighting the single quote immediately after the .[SubProcessID]=

Comment: You certainly fixed the syntax issue but now I am getting a Runtime 3464 error stating that the two fields are not the same data types. How can that be? They are both numerical values.

Comment: which field? `SubProcessID`?

Comment: Yes.  That is a number.  Perhaps the reference to the control Form_frmVAlueChain07e.ID is not getting picked up as a number?

Comment: See the updated answer.... You don't need the `Single Quotes` while appending data values, if the data being passed is a number

Answer (score 0):

try out this ...

```
sql_get = "SELECT tblContacts.ID AS IDResource, tblImmages.Immage, tblContacts.Foto, tblSkillsMatrix01.CurrentLevel, tblSkillsMatrix01.GeneralNotesSymbol, tblSkillsMatrix01.ID, tblSkillsMatrix01.Status, tblSkillsMatrix01.SkillLevelPie, tblSkillsMatrix01.SubProcessID, tblSkillsMatrix01.Contact, tblTeams.Team, tblValueChain01.MacroProcess, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelOneStatus, tblSkillsMatrix01.AsOfDateL1, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelTwoStatus, tblSkillsMatrix01.AsOfDateL2, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelThreeStatus, tblSkillsMatrix01.AsOfDateL3, " & _
"tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelFourStatus , tblSkillsMatrix01.AsOfDateL4, tblSkillsMatrix01.GeneralNotes, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelOneNotes, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelTwoNotes, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelThreeNotes, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelFourNotes, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelOneNotesSymbol, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelTwoNotesSymbol, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelThreeNotesSymbol, tblSkillsMatrix01.LevelFourNotesSymbol, tblSkillsMatrix01.ExpectedCmplDateL1, tblSkillsMatrix01.ExpectedCmplDateL2, tblSkillsMatrix01.ExpectedCmplDateL3 , tblSkillsMatrix01.ExpectedCmplDateL4 FROM (tblTeams INNER JOIN (tblContacts INNER JOIN (tblSkillsMatrix01 INNER JOIN tblImmages ON tblSkillsMatrix01.SkillLevelPie = tblImmages.ID) ON tblContacts.ID = tblSkillsMatrix01.Contact) ON tblTeams.ID = tblContacts.Team) INNER JOIN tblValueChain01 ON tblContacts.Group = tblValueChain01.IDMacroProcesso WHERE [tblValueChain01].[MacroProcess]= '" & Me.MacroProcess & "'" and [tblSkillsMatrix01].[SubProcessID]= '" & Form_frmValueChain07e.ID & "'"
Me.frmValueChain14.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```